# Use a Web Deployment Package or NuGet package as build artifact in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: asp.net-core, continuous-integration, nuget, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am using Visual Studio Team Services for Continous Integration, Continous Deployment for a ASP .NET Core project. In VSTS when we create a build definition, we are required to provide a repository link from where VSTS will get the code and then build it and we can use the build artifacts in VSTS release definition.

I do not want to link my repository with VSTS build definition. Instead I want the ability to produce a Web Deployment Package or a NuGet package for my project (I wont mind even if I have to do it out of VSTS) and then use that package as build artifact in my release definition.

Is that possible? if yes then how can I acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a package management feed as a release artifact. When choosing an artifact source, change the dropdown from *Build* to *Package Management*.

However, you still need to publish your NuGet packages to the feed first.

Comment: After publishing the NuGet package to the feed and using it as build artifact, I am getting this error in Deploy IIS Website/App Phase: ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern. I am not sure what should I enter in 'Packages or Folder' field. I have tried this: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg but getting the same error

Comment: @FarooqHanif Web Deploy package is a zip file, but nuget package file is .nupkg. (You can include the web deploy package file into a nuget package, and unzip the nuget package file, but it is the bad way)

Answer (score 0):

First, there are many source types of artifact in Release, as Daniel said that you can choose Package Management as release artifact, but you need to push the package to the feed first.

With Build artifact, it needs to be generated through Build and you need to specify the sources (Get sources).

Secondly, you can don’t link any artifacts in release definition, and download/copy the Web Deployment Package or NuGet package from a shared folder, other machine or other ways (e.g. FTP server) through related tasks, such as Copy Files, Windows Machine File Copy, PowerShell (download files programming) etc…

Comment: how can I use a web deployment package as build artifact ?

Comment: @FarooqHanif Regarding build artifact, you need to do it through build (Publish Build Artifact task).

Comment: but how do I configure VSTS to use a folder stored in my computer. For example, in case of Nuget packages, we install Package management from marketplace and then we get an option labeled as 'Package' in Release artifacts. What are the prerequisites of using a Web Deployment Package as a Release artifact?

Comment: @FarooqHanif Do not specify Release artifact,if the web deployment package is in a shared folder and can be accessible from agent machine, you can specify the UNC path in Deploy IIS APP task. For other ways, such as FTP, Other machine, you can add the task to download it to agent machine and use it in the tasks.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the help :)